# Отправка POST данных в Slim Fmwk

Tags: framework, php

Я вообще не пойму, как там работает роутинг, что я при отправке формы попадаю на страницу ошибки. Может, кто знает, что да как там?

```
$app->get('/signup', function() use ($app, $fenom) {

    require './app/models/users.php';

    $data = array(
        'action'    =>   '/signup'
    );

    if ($app->request->isPost('signup')){

        # подготавливем переменные

        $login     = $app->request()->post('login');
        $email     = $app->request()->post('email');
        $password  = $app->request()->post('password');

        $error     = null;

        # проверяем логин

        if (empty($login))
            $error .= '<div>Вы не ввели логин</div>';
        else if (mb_strlen($login) < 3 || mb_strlen($login) > 15)
            $error .= '<div>Логин короче 3 или длинше 15</div>';
        else if ( ! preg_match('#^[0-9A-Za-z_-]+#', $login))
            $error .= '<div>Логин содержит недопустимые символы</div>';

        # проверяем email

        if (empty($email))
            $error .= '<div>Вы не ввели Email</div>';
        else if ( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            $error .= '<div>Email введен не корректно</div>';

        # проверяем пароли

        if (empty($password))
            $error .= '<div>Вы не ввели пароль</div>';
        else if (mb_strlen($password) < 8)
            $error .= '<div>Пароль не должен быть короче 8</div>';

        # если есть ошибки выводим их, если нет записываем юзера

        if (isset($error)) {
            $data = array('error' => $error);
        } else {
            $users = Model::factory('users')->create();
            $users->login    = $app->request()->post('login');
            $users->email    = $app->request()->post('email');
            $users->password = $app->request()->post('password');
            $users->save();
        }

    } $fenom->display("users/signup.tpl", $data);
});
```

Comment: Номер ошибки какой? 
Что в логах написано?

Comment: @intertex, да просто 404. Я попросту не могу разобраться с роутингом.

Answer (score 1):

А форма отправляется точно методом GET?

```
$app->get('/signup', function() use ($app, $fenom) {
```

По всей видимости все же POST, поэтому нужно писать

```
$app->post('/signup', function() use ($app, $fenom) {
```

Фреймворк очень простой, [вот про роутинг](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Routing-Overview)